# When trying to create a search view in java, I get a list of errors

Tags: java, android-studio, searchview

I am working on cs50x and I am trying to create a search view following the steps they gave me. However, when i try to open the app, the logcat outputs this:

```
2020-05-30 15:15:45.371 20144-20144/edu.harvard.cs50.pokedex E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: edu.harvard.cs50.pokedex, PID: 20144
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.widget.SearchView
at edu.harvard.cs50.pokedex.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:34)
```

And a buch of other erros, but I have checked them and they doesnt matter. The point is that the course is telling me to use the `androidx` version of the searchviw in the `main_menu.xml` but it says it is incompatible. 
Here is my main_menu.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

And my adapter (The sarch view part):

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new PokemonFilter();
}

private class PokemonFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint.length() == 0 || constraint == null) {
            results.values = pokemon;
            results.count = pokemon.size();
        }
        else {
            List<Pokemon> filteredPokemon = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Pokemon pokemon : filteredPokemon) {
                if (pokemon.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                    filteredPokemon.add(pokemon);
                }
            }
            results.values = filteredPokemon;
            results.count = filteredPokemon.size();
        }
        return results;
        }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults results) {
        filtered = (List<Pokemon>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private PokedexAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    adapter = new PokedexAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView searchView = (androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener((androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener) this);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String newText) {
    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: What's the current issue, exactly? Presumably, that Exception happened before you changed to the fully-qualified class name `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` in the `getActionView()` line, since you likely have `android.widget.SearchView` imported at the top of the class. That Exception won't happen with the given code, though, so it's not really clear what you're asking, here.

Comment: I havent changed anything. This is the code that makes the error. I have checked other questions, and the ansewr is to put the androidx.appcompact.widget.SearchView, but used that since the begining. When I try to run the app, it gets closed and that error gets outputed in the logcat

Comment: Which is line 34 in `MainActivity`?

Comment: androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView searchView = (androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();  Just to clarify, the course tells me to add the onCreateOptionsMenu like this: public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        return true;
    }

Comment: The code posted in the question won't throw the given Exception, because you're using `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` everywhere. That code in your comment is likely to throw the given Exception, though, if you have the wrong `SearchView` class imported. Are you sure you're looking at the most recent logs? In any case, make sure that the import at the top of the class is `import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;`, not `android.widget.SearchView`. Then clean and rebuild your project (under the Build menu), and try it again.

Comment: The errors in the post get output when i put the code that the course provide, as i said specified before. When I run the code in the post I get this errors: '''E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: edu.harvard.cs50.pokedex, PID: 28788
    java.lang.ClassCastException: edu.harvard.cs50.pokedex.MainActivity cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener. And the app keeps closing'''

Comment: Fix the import statement, as I mention above. When you do that, you won't have to fully-qualify the `SearchView` class everywhere, btw. That is, you can just use `SearchView` instead of `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` in the code.

Comment: Ohhh okok, sorry for the mistake. Thanks man. How do I implement SearchView.OnQueryTextListener though? And I am new here so, can you tell me how to do the inline code in comments?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You already have it implemented; it was just the wrong type, 'cause of the import mix-up.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just realized that the second part of your comment was about these comments here. Apologies. You can highlight inline code by surrounding it with backticks; i.e., `\``. That works in questions and answers, too, for inline keywords and such. I would mention, though, that if you need to post a big chunk of code or XML, it's usually more appropriate to edit your post, and add it there. Just FYI. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks man! Just so you know, I solved it. Had to watch a bunch of youtube tutorials, but it was worth it.  `so like this?` edit: it was like that